How can I add 'DOES NOT EXIST' to my SQL query?
I need to insert a new row from temp table (temp) if it does not exist in table (t). The problem I have is that there is not a primary key and the temp table is truncated each time its imported. I am merging the data from temp to t with a stored procedure but I only want to import rows that do not exist. I have tried at the start of the insert query:
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost_NEW sa 
               LEFT JOIN FPS_LZ.FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost lz 
                         ON lz.Drug_Identifier = sa.Drug_Identifier
               WHERE sa.Drug_Identifier = lz.Drug_Identifier 
                 AND lz.Effective_Date <> sa.Effective_Date)

and at the end of the insert query:
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost_NEW)

Full insert query for better reference:
--IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost_NEW sa LEFT JOIN FPS_LZ.FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost lz ON lz.Drug_Identifier = sa.Drug_Identifier WHERE sa.Drug_Identifier = lz.Drug_Identifier AND lz.Effective_Date <> sa.Effective_Date)

    INSERT INTO FPS_SA.FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost_NEW
    (
    Drug_Identifier,
    Identifier_Type,
    Drug_Group,
    Brand_Generic,
    PAC,
    PAC_Low,
    PAC_High,
    PAC_Retail,
    Error_Code,
    Effective_Date,
    End_Date,
    PAC_Model_Version
   
    )
    SELECT lz.Drug_Identifier,
       lz.Identifier_Type,
       lz.Drug_Group,
       lz.Brand_Generic,
       lz.PAC,
       lz.PAC_Low,
       lz.PAC_High,
       lz.PAC_Retail,
       lz.Error_Code,
       lz.Effective_Date,
       lz.End_Date,
       lz.PAC_Model_Version
      
    FROM FPS_LZ.fps.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost lz LEFT OUTER JOIN          FPS_SA.FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost sa ON lz.Drug_Identifier = sa.Drug_Identifier`
--WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost_NEW)

I tried an "IF NOT EXISTS" at the beginning of the query and/or a "WHERE NOT EXISTS" at the end     of the query.
I keep getting duplicate rows in the destination table.

I should have added that the Drug_Identifier, Identifier_Type, Drug_Group, Brand_Generic all will remain the same when a new row is added but the effective date will change. So basically, I want to add the same row again but with the new effective date.

Can you repost your code without commented out sql code? Its very hard to understand what you mean by "trying at the start" and "trying at the end" when these things you tried are comments. Commented code will do nothing and there is no point in trying it.

What DBMS is this? Please tag it, as answers can vary materially between each

I think I get what you mean though ...

I think the problem is your "if not exists" or "where exists" checks are much to broad. If anything exists (or nothing exists) all the rows are inserted (or not inserted). You need a check for each row that is to be inserted (or not inserted). In technical terms, you probably intend to use a correlated subquery here - a row by row existence check.

A reproducible example would make it easier for us to help you - a create table script that creates some tables and adds some data to them, and then your sample query with the sample results (basically - so we can test the query and test a proposed solution).

Also the logic needs clarity. Why does one of your tries with "exists" checks use effective date, but the other(s) do not? This is very hard to answer as it stands.

Make it easy to assist you - simplify your example. Provide a complete [mcve].

If there is no matching via a unique key you must decide which columns to include when comparing rows from each table. For example, the following would identify rows from the new table that do not exist in the existing table:
SELECT
      t.*
FROM FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost_NEW t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                 FROM FPS_LZ.fps.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost lz 
                 WHERE  lz.Drug_Identifier = t.Drug_Identifier
                    AND lz.Identifier_Type = t.Identifier_Type
                    AND lz.Drug_Group = t.Drug_Group
                    AND lz.Brand_Generic = t.Brand_Generic
                    AND lz.PAC = t.PAC
                    AND lz.PAC_Low = t.PAC_Low
                    AND lz.PAC_High = t.PAC_High
                    AND lz.PAC_Retail = t.PAC_Retail
                    AND lz.Error_Code = t.Error_Code
                    AND lz.Effective_Date = t.Effective_Date
                    AND lz.End_Date = t.End_Date
                    AND lz.PAC_Model_Version = t.PAC_Model_Version
                 )

In the reverse, identify rows from the existing table that do not exist in the new table just adjust the table references:
SELECT
      lz.*
FROM FPS_LZ.fps.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost lz
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                 FROM FPS.Predictive_Acquisition_Cost_NEW t 
                 WHERE  lz.Drug_Identifier = t.Drug_Identifier
                    AND lz.Identifier_Type = t.Identifier_Type
                    AND lz.Drug_Group = t.Drug_Group
                    AND lz.Brand_Generic = t.Brand_Generic
                    AND lz.PAC = t.PAC
                    AND lz.PAC_Low = t.PAC_Low
                    AND lz.PAC_High = t.PAC_High
                    AND lz.PAC_Retail = t.PAC_Retail
                    AND lz.Error_Code = t.Error_Code
                    AND lz.Effective_Date = t.Effective_Date
                    AND lz.End_Date = t.End_Date
                    AND lz.PAC_Model_Version = t.PAC_Model_Version
                 )

The main point is that to use NOT EXISTS(subquery) that subquery must contain a where clause with predicates that compare values from both tables. In particular note how each predicate in there where clause refers to lz (existing) and t (new).
nb: "select null" or "select *" or "select 1" can be used in the subquery as it will make no difference to the outcome. The vital part of the subquery in a NOT EXISTS construct is the where clause.
